# Why are the 'discrete' one-sample Cramer-von Mises tests in Choulakian et al. 1994 written as such

Tags: goodness-of-fit

Given a set of data $X$ of length $N$, with a theoretical probability distribution $F$ and empirical distribution $F_n$, the Cramer-von Mises statistic is essentially the sum of the squared distance between the empirical and theoretical distributions, which is essentially the L2 norm. If we have discrete data the estimation shouldn't change much, I naively assume. When dealing with an actual sample I think this should be evaluated as:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N (F_n(x_i) - F(x_i))^2.
$$

For the related Anderson-Darling test we could write:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(F_n(x_i) - F(x_i))^2}{F(x_i)(1-F(x_i))}.
$$

In [Choulakian, Lockhart, and Stephens (1994)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3315828), the authors define the computation slightly differently, instead using the difference in the cumulative counts. Then, rather than dividing by $N^2$ they divide by $N$ and what looks like the density of each $x_i$. See the screenshot below. Their equation would be the same as the above, if $p_j$ in their notation was simply $N^{-1}$, so where does this discrepancy arise?
[image]

P.S. For evaluating the significance of the statistic I'm aware one needs to take into account if the parameters of $F$ are fitted, and would use essentially a parametric bootstrap/monte carlo procedure to evaluate the distribution of the statistic under the null hypothesis, similar to a K-S test.

Choulakian, V., R. A. Lockhart and M. A. Stephens, Cramér-von Mises Statistics for Discrete Distributions, *The Canadian Journal of Statistics / La Revue Canadienne de Statistique* 1994 p 125-137 doi:10.2307/3315828 and jstor:3315828